# Lagging jquery preloader image

Tags: jquery, image, preload

Am using jquery to load a preloading image before the main content is loaded. The problem is that, when I click on the link, the loading image takes atleast 5secs before it shows. I would like it to show immediately I click on the link before the content shows.

Here's the jquery;

```
$(function() {
    $("li#tabs.popup a").click(function(e) {
        $("#popup").slideDown().addClass('active');
        $('#popup').html('<center><img src="images/loader.gif" /></center>');
        $('#popup').load('wishlist.php');
        $('li#tabs.popup a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

After much fidgeting I found the answer to the question. For some reason, placing the loader above all other functions will cause it to load smoothly and immediately onclick.

So instead of the code above, I did

```
$(function() {
    $("li#tabs.popup a").click(function(e) {
        $('#popup').html('<center><img src="images/loader.gif" /></center>');
        $("#popup").slideDown().addClass('active');
        $('#popup').load('wishlist.php');
        $('li#tabs.popup a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

now it works just perfect!

Comment: where is your loader image being set? i.e is the loader.gif actually used anywhere on your page before being set by jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You're title is a little confusing, so it seems you actually want to preload your preloading image :)

We've used [this script](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_automatically_preload_images_from_css_with_jquery/) in the past to ensure that all image references in our css are preloaded. I would then change your "preloading" animation to use css (you can set the background image to your animated gif) rather than creating an image tag on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this happens because when you start displaying the image as html content, it loads and then shows up. You could already load it onto your page, for instance:

```
<div id="popup">
    <div id="spinner"> <!-- Assuming that it has display: none in CSS -->
        <center><img src="images/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></center>
    </div>

    <!-- Load the content here. -->
</div>
```

And your script would look like

```
$(function() {
    $("li#tabs.popup a").click(function(e) {
        $('#popup').find('#spinner')
                   .show()
                   .end()
                   .load('wishlist.php')
                   .slideDown()
                   .addClass('active');

        $('li#tabs.popup a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

*Sidenote:* And you really don't have to write `$('li#tabs')`, simply `$('#tabs')` (or more appropriately `$('.tabs')` would do. When you set the selector to `li#tabs` it causes Sizzle to filter the result of `document.getElementById('tabs')` to see if the matching element's tagname is `li`.